# SQS stops receiving messages when MySQL is locked

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs

So, I have SQS setup and it receives messages from my Laravel 8 application by way of a Job. A request comes in and this request has data that is popped onto the queue. The queue worker then processes this message and writes it to the database. I am adding an index to the table that the data is written to, the alter table command locks the table during this operation. While the table is locked SQS does not receive any new messages despite the request processor working and dispatching jobs without error.

Any ideas why this would prevent the dispatched jobs from being queued?

```
class ProcessIncomingAISData implements ShouldQueue{

use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $ais_message;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(String $ais_message)
{
    $this->ais_message = $ais_message;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{  
    try{
        $ais = AISData::factory($this->ais_message);
        $ais->save();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        Log::error($e);
    }        
}
```

This job is called by:

```
ProcessIncomingAISData::dispatch($data)->onQueue('ais-incoming-data-queue');
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is whatever process it is in Laravel that queues the messages does not work when the table is locked. Without any actual code of what you're doing I can only guess though

Comment: There is no interaction with the database until the message is taken from the queue... It is really simple. I have added some code for the Job that dispatched the job and handles it.

Comment: is the `ais-incoming-data-queue` backed by SQS?

Comment: @apokryfos yes. I have processed over 15million messages with this system so far.

Comment: I think I have misinterpreted the graph information. That chart is not the number of messages received by the queue. The number of messages received by the queue is actually the graph of the "number of messages sent". So it is still receiving messages, the graph I showed drops to zero because the queue worker can not process the message because the MySQL table is locked so the message stays on the queue. Crisis diverted.